# How to go with inline preview for user content input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have text area which allow the use to write markdown and share some links. In server side I have class with convert the markdown to html and fetch the urls. What I need is to provide the user to preview the inserted input before submit. Should I use:

- Short polling
- Long polling
- Websocket
- Server-Sent Events (with ActionController::Live::SSE)

What is the best approach? And how background jobs would fit in the setup.

Comment: I would using consider [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) which is a javascript Markdown parser. It will let you just render the previews in the client instead of shuffling it back and forth to the server. Even if you did do it on the server most of your suggestions are total overkill for just parsing markdown which should not be that expensive. You don't need polling either as you can just create a change event handler on the editor which updates the preview.

Comment: It's not just the parsing markdown, I am fetching the urls on the server also. So I client side solution will not do. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "fetching the urls"?

Comment: Convert any url to rich media. Something like https://iframely.com/